# С помощью чего можно получить текст с этой картинки?

Tags: python, opencv, текст, pil, tesseract

нужно получить текст с обработанного изображения с помощью любых библиотек(кроме нейросетей). На вход подавалась данная картинка [image: введите сюда описание изображения], код обработки:

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

im = Image.open("7TXB6Q.png")
im = im.convert("P")
im2 = Image.new("P",im.size,255)

im = im.convert("P")

temp = {}

for x in range(im.size[1]):
  for y in range(im.size[0]):
    pix = im.getpixel((y,x))
    temp[pix] = pix
    if pix > 2: # these are the numbers to get
      im2.putpixel((y,x),0)

im2.save("output.png")

im = cv2.imread("output.png")

im = im[0:90, 35:150]

cv2.imwrite("output.png",im)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("gray",gray)
cv2.waitKey()
```

После обработки картинка выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Пробовал получить текст с помощью метода `image_to_string`

```py
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
print(data)
```

Но он выдаёт на выходе строку `, FERRE`
Хотелось бы узнать возможно есть более качественные методы получения текста, или возможно, наболее подходящие для обработки изображений данного типа различные алгоритмы, любая ваша корректировка или совет будут очень ценны для меня, т.к я новичок в данной области

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что без нейросетей и в частности слоёв конволюции тут что-то получится.

Comment: @CrazyElf, для нейросетей понадобится обучающая выборка из нескольких десятков тысяч предварительно размеченных картинок или придется написать свой модуль, который будет из текста генерить такие картинки для создания обучающей выборки...

Comment: @CrazyElf, Я пытался гуглить впринципе распознование captch(к сожалению нужной мне, там не оказалось) без использования нейросетей, таких статей мало, но они показывают, что такое возможно

Comment: @shalor1k Капчи сейчас проще за деньги разгадывать, есть специальные сайты со смешными ценами. Сидят условные "индусы" и за копейки разгадывают. Все другие способы - придётся повозиться. Возможно, тут можно подобрать какие-то фильтры для OpenCV чтобы улучшить качество, но надо подбирать.

Comment: @MaxU Да наверняка готовые натренированные сетки можно найти, задача то типическая. Но в целом да, можно сэмулировать трансформации и помехи и натренировать сетку. Просто не будет, ну а как ещё?

Answer (score 1):

1. По возможности хорошо бы увеличить разрешение картинки, текст на которой Вы хотите распознать, тут нужно будет долго провозиться для подбора оптимального увеличения. Я использовал метод resize у CV2, помимо смены разрешения, у него есть такой атрибут "interpolation", вроде бы правильно написал, так вот хорошим методом при увеличении разрешения является cv2.INTER_CUBIC. Пробовал cv.INTER_LINEAR, но с ним похуже, но с другой стороны пишут, что он быстрее работает.
2. Убрать шумы с помощью CV2. Зайдите на оф. сайт CV2 и найдите там уроки по работе, долистайте до раздела работы с картинками, там будет очень много информации по удалении шумов, попробуйте все методы.
3. Вы применяете какое-то странное преобразование в черно-белый цвет, у Вас после преобразования BGR-GRAY остается множество различных оттенков. Попробуйте другие методы преобразования. BINARY-метод оставляет только 2 цвета, без оттенков.